# How can I allow a "development" program through the firewall?

Tags: network, java, firewall

I have an application (java) that I compile/run through netbeans, I want to access it from a different computer. [Opening a port](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/33871/75462) might be the best solution, though if so I'd like to be a little more restrictive than just opening to any IP. I actually think restricting via MAC address would be a better solution (do to IP's changing via dhcp but the computers not). Suggestions welcome.

Comment: Why not set up a VPN and connect to your network that way?

Comment: because point to point vpn for 2 computers seems like a lot of work compared to what should be a 1 line firewall rule.

Comment: also because afaik vpns operate over the IP stack, and both of these are laptops, and I don't want to be constantly reconfiguring the vpn... (unless there's something magical I don't know, that allows me to have an autoconfiguring vpn between the 2, and isn't apple specific because my other laptop is linux)