# How to open a specific port in Firewall OS X 10.9.4

Tags: macos, firewall

How do I open a specific port in the firewall?
I can not use the "allow connections from application" as I want to open the port for Jenkins, that is not on the list...

Comment: What port(s) and protocols do you want Jenkins to be able to listen on? This post will help you see what ports it's configured on... http://stackoverflow.com/a/10106086/475228

Comment: On proto Tcp port 8080

Comment: Would this post covering `ipfw` be relevant? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33871/how-can-i-open-a-port-not-application-in-the-os-x-10-6-firewall

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple's OS X Mavericks contains three firewalls. First of all, the Application Level Firewall which can be configured using the system settings. But there is also ipfw, a packet filtering firewall like netfilter/iptables on GNU/Linux and pf (FreeBSD/OpenBSD).

You can either configure *ipfw* using the command line, or using a graphical front-end like the free/libre [WaterRoof](http://www.hanynet.com/waterroof/).

You could start with an ipfw command like:

```
sudo ipfw add 31010 allow tcp from any to any dst-port 8080
```

Comment: ipfw is deprecated and gone in El Capitan

Comment: @slashdottir How can I use this command with pfctl?

Comment: @user233428 It's been quite a while since I had to do this, but checking my bash history, looks like I used: `echo "rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 19131" | sudo pfctl -ef -`

Answer (score 26):

I had the same issue under OS X Yosemite (10.10.3).  Found [this blog post](https://rolfje.wordpress.com/2014/05/10/open-a-port-in-osx-mavericks-firewall/) that provides clear instructions.  We can't use ipfw any more, as it's deprecated.  Instead, use pfctl, which unfortunately lacks a nice command line way to tell it to open a port.  Instead, you need to:

1. Open /etc/pf.conf in a text editor.
2. Add a line like this:

> # Open port 8080 for TCP on all interfaces
>
> pass in proto tcp from any to any port 8080

3. Save the file.
4. Load the changes with:

> sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf

If you need to open a udp port, change `tcp` to `udp`, if you need both, add a second line.  Additional detail can be found in `man pf.conf`.

Also make sure your server is listening on the actual interface you want it accessible over (or all interfaces, using `0.0.0.0` or `::0`), not localhost (`127.0.0.1` or `::1`).

Comment: Whoa, reboot? Do you really have to reboot to open a port?

Comment: passing `-n` to pfctl verifies the rules, and pointedly does not load them.  Use just  `-f /etc/pf.conf` to load the rules.  Verify they are loaded with `pfctl -sr`.  However, while pfctl rules is necessary it does not appear by itself to be sufficient to allow access to a El Capitan on a given port.

Comment: ... One must also make sure the application is bound to the host name (not `localhost`); one gets the hostname with `$ hostname` on the command line.  Also, one can restart the firewall, instead of rebooting, by going to System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Firewall -> Turn Off Firewall and then Turn On Firewall.

Comment: @Keen fantastic avatar - great memories!

Answer (score 6):

ipfw is deprecated by Apple. Mountain Lion and later use pfctl.

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5413

Comment: can you post the specific command to open a port?

Comment: If you want to add a specific port, then I think you need to edit the configuration file ( see http://krypted.com/mac-security/a-cheat-sheet-for-using-pf-in-os-x-lion-and-up/ and search for the part with 192.168).  On the other hand, if you want to ensure an application is not blocked, https://jamfnation.jamfsoftware.com/discussion.html?id=6566 has a pretty good summary in the final comment.  I still mostly use 10.6, so I haven't worked with pfctl much.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one liner rather than requiring the user to mess around with Vim. Useful for automation.

```
sed -i '' -e '$a\pass in proto tcp from any to any port 8080' /etc/pf.conf; pfctl -vnf /etc/pf.conf
```

Or an alternative for Linux users

```
sed -i -e '$a\pass in proto tcp from any to any port 8080' /etc/pf.conf; pfctl -vnf /etc/pf.conf
```

Just make sure you change `8080` in the example to whatever you have in mind. Swap tcp with udp if you like.