# How do I open port 5672 in OS X 10.9.5?

Tags: macos

I'd like to allow users on my local network to access the RabbitMQ server that's running on my Mac.

I tried adding `pass in proto tcp from any to any port 5672` to /etc/pf.conf, applying the rule and rebooting but the port is still closed.

EDIT: I'm asking this question because the accepted answer in the "possible duplicate" references a deprecated API for achieving what I'm after. The other answers to that question do not solve my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a specific port in Firewall OS X 10.9.4](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142778/how-to-open-a-specific-port-in-firewall-os-x-10-9-4)

Comment: Which firewall are you using? By default none of the various firewalls is turned on.

Comment: The firewall is off, but nmap still says the port is still closed.