# How can I open a port (not application) in the macOS Sierra firewall?

Tags: macos, firewall, ipfw

I am trying to follow up on this [thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33871/how-can-i-open-a-port-not-application-in-the-os-x-10-6-firewall) and to update it for macOS Sierra (and probably all versions since Yosemite).

In that thread, a way to open a single port in the OS's firewall was suggested:

```
sudo ipfw add 40000 allow tcp from any to any dst-port portnum
```

However, since Yosemite, ipfw was replaced with pf and, unless I am mistaken, pfctl should therefore be used.

What would the above command translate to?

Answer (score 2):

To open a port you would use the following line(s):

```
pass in proto tcp from any to any port 40000
pass in proto tcp from any to any port 80
pass in proto {tcp, udp} from any to any port 53
pass in from any to any port 3601
```

To quick-start pf and open a port with **one** of the lines above use e.g.:

```
echo "pass in proto tcp from any to any port 40000" | sudo pfctl -ef -
```

To test the rule(s) use: `sudo pfctl -s rules`

After a reboot you would have to enter the command again, because pf is not started automatically.

By default the pf.conf file has no *blocking all* rule. So even after starting pf with `sudo pfctl -e` nothing is blocked.

If you don't want to dive deeply into pf/pf.conf/pfctl, I recommend to use a pfctl GUI like the free [Murus Lite](http://murusfirewall.com/) to configure pf.

Comment: Mac OS Sierra keeps complaining about pfctl interfering with internal firewall by flushing rules that have been set on startup. What? Are there different firewalls? How come? ... As a conclusion this sounds pretty ridiculous to me as it renders to be unnecessarily painful to do something as simple as open a port for incoming connections, in my case to expose homebrewn dnsmasq to local network under Sierra. (With this "application" not listed as application to be enabled the common way.)

Comment: @cepharum macOS Sierra provides two different firewalls: pf (no Apple GUI) and the Application Firewall (System Prefs > Security > Firewall). Feel free to ask a separate question covering your problem.